# CSS float property on thimble

Tags: html, css

I'm using google chrome for my browser and i'm using mozilla thimble to code bcause my instructor told us to do it there even though I prefer notepad.

So... I'm trying to make these 2 divs float next to each other.

this is the website - https://jasminebanares.makes.org/thimble/MTM0MDgwMTAyNA==/mini-blog

this is the html:

```
    <div id="content">

     <div id="1">
      <p id="date" align="right">Friday - 13 Jun 2014</p>
      <p id="blog" align="center">Kaila didn't sit with us at recess today. At lunch she sat with for a short perod of time then Anna invited her to sit wth them and she tagged along. <br />Mylene said I got a 100% on the science test yesterday. Then I came across my other friends and they said the same thing. hhmmm.... I'll just wait until monday.</p>
      <p id="feeling">feeling 'DISAPPOINTED and EAGER'</p>
    </div>
    <div id="2">
      <p id="date" align="right">Thursday - 12 Jun 2014</p>
      <p id="blog" align="center">Met this new Filipino girl at recess today. Her name is Kaila. She's in 3 of my classes. I wonder what she's like...</p>
      <p id="feeling">feeling 'ANXIOUS'</p>
     </div>

  </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #content {
    border-radius:20px;
    background:white;
    opacity:0.6;
    overflow:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:30%;
    left:20%;
    right:5%;
    height:70%;
    width:75%;}

  #date {
    font-family: 'Didact Gothic', sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
    color:#7A7A7A;}

  #blog {
    font-family: 'Handlee', cursive;
    font-size:18px;
    color:black;}

  #feeling {
    font-family: 'Neucha', cursive;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#4D4D4D;}

  #1 {
    position:relative;
    width:45%;
    left:3%;
    right:4%;
    float:left;}
  #2 {
    position:relative;
    width:45%;
    right:3%;
    float:left;}
```

Thank you very much. Please tell me any errors i have made and correct them if necessary..

Once again - Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Set 50% (I take 49% to be on safe side) width of both the div

```
#1 {
    position:relative;
    width:45%;
    left:3%;
    right:4%;
    float:left;
    width:49%
}

#2 {
    position:relative;
    width:45%;
    right:3%;
    float:left;
    width:49%
}
```

Comment: thanks but I've tried this and it didn't work... Thanks for your opinion though :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code was on the right track, the problem was that you were using a CSS ID selector that started with a *number*, which is invalid and won't get read by the browser. Class selectors may start with a number, but not IDs. This doesn't meant ID's won't work in HTML if they start with a number, it just means CSS can't read them directly as selectors.

Here's a **[Fiddle showing the solution](http://jsfiddle.net/timmah/f4p2v/)**

For example:

```
#1 {
    /* CSS styles here */
}
```

Will be ignored, hence why your `div`s weren't displaying the style applied to them. When the ID of those `div`s is changed to start with a *letter*, they suddenly start responding:

```
#div1 {
    /* CSS styles here */
}
```

If you can't change your IDs for some reason, here's a [handy way of selecting them anyway](http://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/)

Comment: Thanks!! I remember reading somewhere about that thing... Thanks, I'll try it now! :)

Comment: BTW, i wanted to make everything ids so it looked neat with all # only :)

Comment: There's no problem using ID's rather than classes, but if they start with numbers you can't select them with CSS in the traditional way